# MongoDB: Find items with the user id

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a product collection and a user collection where I reference user to my product collection.

So far what I am trying to achieve here is to get only the products that are created by that user.

```
const getOwnerProduct = expressAsyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    const activeUser = await User.findById(req.user._id)
    const pageSize = 10
    const page = Number(req.query.pageNumber) || 1

    const items = { user: { _id: activeUser } }

    const count = await Product.countDocuments({ ...items } )

    const products = await Product.find({ ...items }).limit(pageSize).skip(pageSize * (page - 1))
    res.json({ products, page, pages: Math.ceil(count / pageSize) })
})
```

Here's the Product Schema:

```
const productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String
    },
    rating: {
        type: Number,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },
    image: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        default: 0
    },

}, { timestamps: true
})
```

And here's the userSchema:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    phone: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    role: {
        type: String,
        enum: ['administrator', 'productOwner', 'regular'],
        default: 'regular'
     }
}, { timestamps: true
})
```

Here's the router:

```
app.use('/api/products', productRoutes)
router.route('/').get(getProducts, admin).get(getOwnerProducts, productOwner)
```

For some reason this doesn't work. I think my query on mongodb is not correct.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Comment: please provide schema of products, what is the reference field name?

Comment: Updated my question. Basically, I simply wants to pull up the products that are created by the productOwner which is the user that is currently logged in.

Comment: just change this line to `const items = { user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.user._id) }`

Comment: It did not work at alll

Answer (score 0):

Here instead of  `const products = await Product.find({ ...items })` you can try

```
await User.findById(req.user._id).forEach(element =>{Product.find({user=element._id})});
```

or

```
await User.findById(req.user._id).forEach(element =>{Product.find(user=element._id)});
```